# MongoDB find() which is retrieving only one property from the collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection of blog posts where the structure of the records is {title, author, contents} and I want to retrieve all the names of all the authors I am doing this:

```
this.db.collection("ContentText").find("authors");
```

but my output is `undefined`
Can someone point out the error?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.db.collection("ContentText").distinct("author");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.db.collection('<collection_name>').find(<queryObject>,{author:1});
```

This query will return you array of authors with _id, you can exclude _id by

`{_id:0,author:1}`

For more read [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)